# How do I retain the value of a for loop variable when the loop is over?

Tags: lua

I'm trying to find something in a loop in Lua, and when I'm done I need to use the location I found.

```
for j = 1,100 do
    <do some stuff>
    if <some test> then
            break
    end
end
if j >= 100 then
    return
end
```

Unfortunately, I get an error which suggests that after the `for` loop exits, the value of `j` is nil.   How do I use the value that j ended at?  Obviously I could create an extra variable and assign it right before I break, but that just seems wrong, and I've never seen another language set the loop variable to nil when the loop ends, so I'm wondering if there isn't a better way to accomplish this.

Comment: @agentb26: I don't believe that will work. You can create another variable j before the loop, but it's a separate variable whose value won't be affected by the loop. The loop variable j is still unavailable outside the loop. See http://ideone.com/OJuOUv

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The loop variable is only visible inside the for loop block. You can get around this by creating another variable as suggested in [PIL **4.3.4 Numeric For**](http://www.lua.org/pil/4.3.4.html).

```
  local index
  for j=1,100 do
     if j == 10 then
       index = j
     end
  end
```

Alternatively, if you are a doing a common operation then using a function with an early return may be best.

```
     function find(tbl, val)
        for i, v in ipairs(tbl) do
          if v == val then
            return i
          end
        end
     end
```